# Hybris 1811 Platform Update terminates in the middle

Tags: java, tomcat, server, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I am trying to do Platform Update on Hybris 1811. In the middle, it gets terminated due to the error below. I tried to build again and to restart the server, but I keep getting the same error. Anybody faced this kind of issue?

```
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1384)

WARN  [hybrisHTTP18] (00003FGJ-ImpEx-Import) [Importer] Import aborted after 0d 00h:00m:00s:327ms
ERROR [hybrisHTTP18] (00003FGJ-ImpEx-Import) [Job] Caught throwable java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock
        at com.hybris.backoffice.cockpitng.dataaccess.facades.type.DefaultPlatformTypeFacadeStrategy.reset(DefaultPlatformTypeFacadeStrategy.java:801)
```

Comment: (1) Is there any error if you do "ant clean all"? (2) Is there any issue if you do Platform Initialize?

Comment: Build is success, no issues. I have a separate data folder so I didn't to initialize. I just want to update

Comment: Is the data folder copied from another server / system? I would check why the NoClassDefFoundError is being displayed. Are the backoffice extensions in the localextensions.xml?

Comment: Yes, data folder is copied from another system. I have backoffice extension in localextension.xml

Comment: Have you tried stopping the server, starting the server, and doing Platform Update with all extensions checked (including all settings like Essential Data, Localize Types, etc)? I assume you also copied the database from the other server, not just the data folder.

Comment: I tried restarting the server but it didn't help. I just copied data folder and not database. I am using default hsql. I checked all the checkboxes then I did system update.

Comment: Did you change Hybris version? (like an upgrade?)

Comment: Yes I have upgraded from 6.6 to 1811. now after multiple restart I am completed the system update. but one of my team member still facing the same issue.